# How to stop polling in angular when switching routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a route in angular that calls a function every x seconds to poll for data (using setInterval).  My issue is, when the user navigates to another route the polling is still going on.  How do I stop the polling (clearInterval) when switching to any other route using ui-router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cancel $interval on $scope destroy method. More in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 1):

In `ui-router` routes are analogous to states, `ui-router` provides you with [state lifecycle events](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

One of these events, `$stateChangeSuccess` can be used to to cancel your `$interval` in the event you've tried to change a route/state and succeeded.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event){
    // cancel your $interval here
})
```